# How do I plot this function?

Tags: plotting

I have this function that I need to plot

```
y[x] == 0.140628 + (-3.55298 - 4.10235 E^(0.14212 x))^(-1)
```

I have tried

```
Plot[y[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

but it just gives a blank plot, while wolframalpha does give a line.

Comment: Correct syntax would be y[x_] := instead of `y[x] ==`

Answer (score 4):

Presumably, you did not define y[x] correctly.

```
y[x_] = 0.140628 + (-3.55298 - 4.10235 E^(0.14212 x))^(-1);

Plot[y[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Or to plot an equation

```
Clear[y]

ContourPlot[y == 0.140628 + (-3.55298 - 4.10235 E^(0.14212 x))^(-1),
 {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, .1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please note how a function is defined in Mathematica and the use of [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) (`:=`)

```
y[x_]:= 0.140628 + (-3.55298 - 4.10235*E^(0.14212* x))^(-1)
Plot[y[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```